# Extract the last 1000 revisions from svn server windows

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

We have windows 2008 server with SVN repository, i would like to move this to new windows 2008 server but to new Visual SVN server.

Our SVN repository has grown really big and it contains few projects. Im planning to extract the last 1000 revisions from the repository and then separate the projects. Once i have these i would like to load these projects on to a new SVN server as separate repositories. At the same time i do not want to lose the history. When i get people to relocate their repository checkout to new server, i want the users to be still be able to see the history.

First of all is this possible and if so whats the best way to do this.

If this is not possible, then what is closest to my target that i can achieve?

Many Thanks
Shoaib

Answer (score 0):

Read SVN Book, ask SVN-admin to **perform his job**

Anyway

`svnrdump dump URL/OF/ROOT/OF/PROJECT -r $HEAD-1000:$HEAD > dumpfile`

for every project in the old repo

`svnadmin load --force-uuid < dumplfile`

in every new empty repository